# GUI tool to copy selected intact files/directories, following ddrescue clone? (Autopsy is one-at-a-time)

Tags: linux, gui, ubuntu, archiving, data-recovery

I made a clone of a failing hard disk using GNU ddrescue. Many of the files are okay, and many are broken. I can mount the clone, with its three partitions, in Linux.

My linux file browser (tried Thunar,Nautilus,Nemo) fails to list any files in directories with a problematic file - it shows an error dialog for the file, with a blank directory.

The Autopsy file recovery tool (browser-based GUI) shows them (and it lists the files it can't read) but you have to save them one file at a time, and build the directory structure the file goes in.

I'm looking for a file browser that will show the complete, readable files, so I can directly and quickly copy the intact files - complete with the directory structure.

Thanks for any help.